# Nutch 1.3 and Solr 4.4.0 integration Job failed

Tags: solr, nutch, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl the web using nutch and I followed the documentation steps in the nutch's official web site (run the crawl successfully, copy the scheme-solr4.xml into solr directory). but when I run the

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

I get the following error:

```
Indexer: starting at 2013-08-25 09:17:35
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
    solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
    solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
    solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
    solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
    solr.auth.username : use authentication (default false)
    solr.auth : username for authentication
    solr.auth.password : password for authentication


Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:123)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:195)
```

I have to mention that the solr is running but I cannot browse `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin` (it redirects me to `http://localhost:8983/solr/#`).

On the other hand, when I stop the solr, I get the same error! Does anybody have any idea about what is wrong with my setting?

P.S. the url that I crawl is: `http://localhost/NORC`

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration against: [Solr](http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html) and [Nutch](http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/configuring-nutch-to-crawl-urls.html)

Nutch and Solr's schema files should be the same or you may encounter problems so make sure they match up

Answer (score 0):

When I meet same problem in nutch, the solr's log appear a error message "unknown field host".
After modifying  the schema.xml in solr, the nutch's error vanish.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name of the core inside your command.

e.g.:

```
./bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/#/your_corname urls/ crawl 1
```